# How to get XWindow ID in GTK3?

Tags: python, x11, gtk3

In GTK3, how do I retrieve the XWindow ID? I didn't see anything related to this in GdkWindow.

In documentation, it is said there is a GDK_WINDOW_XID() macro. However, I cannot find the equivalence in Python binding.

Comment: Try importing `GdkX11` and then using `get_xid()` on the `Gdk.Window` (Something like `window.get_window().get_xid()`) .
This solution is mentioned [in this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975899/drawingarea-cannot-get-xid).

Comment: Wow! It works. But I don't understand how importing a module can add functions to an already existing object...

Comment: As mentioned in that post, `get_xid()` is specific to `GdkX11`. As you might be aware that `Gdk.Window` is an abstraction over window of different windowing systems like X11, Wayland, DirectFB (not sure if still supported), win32 etc. XID is something associated with X11 windowing system, thus you need `GdkX11` package specifically