# How I can get DrawingArea window handle in Gtk3?

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject, chromium-embedded

I get this code on CEF Python 3 ([link](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef3/windows/binaries/pygtk_.py))

```
    ...

    self.container = gtk.DrawingArea()
    self.container.set_property('can-focus', True)
    self.container.connect('size-allocate', self.OnSize)
    self.container.show()

    ...

    windowID = self.container.get_window().handle
    windowInfo = cefpython.WindowInfo()
    windowInfo.SetAsChild(windowID)
    self.browser = cefpython.CreateBrowserSync(windowInfo,
            browserSettings={},
            navigateUrl=GetApplicationPath('example.html'))

    ...
```

This code [**self.container.get_window().handle**] don't work with PyGI and GTK3.

I trying port the code from GTK2 to GTK3, how I can do this?

Edited:

---

After some search, I found a tip to make **get_window** work: I call: *self.container.realize()* before *self.container.get_window()*. But I cant't get Window Handle yet.

I need put CEF3 window inside a DrawingArea or any element. How I can do this with PyGI?

Edited:

---

My environment is:

Windows 7

Python 2.7 and Python 3.2

Comment: `self.container.get_window()` should work, but it might return `None` if the `GtkWidget` is not realized yet. Maybe you can pass the output of `get_window()` to `SetAsChild()`? You should not need to know the low-level window handles.

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html

Comment: @TorkelBjørnson-Langen, thanks for response. I try use the get_window() result with SetAsChild(). However, SetAsChild() method expect a integer parameter. I need XID of this get_window() to pass to SetAsChild(). Do you known how I can get it?

Comment: No I do not. But this post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732838/how-to-get-xwindow-id-in-gtk3

Comment: @TorkelBjørnson-Langen, thanks for your help. I cannot found a Python Binding that work in Win32. I try everything. Do you known if exist an alternative?

Answer (score 5):

Sadly there seems to be no progress on the python gobject introspection to fix this and make `gdk_win32_window_get_handle` available (reported a bug in the gnome bugtracker quite a while ago) - it is also quite needed for Python GStreamer and Windows ...

So I followed the suggestion of totaam and used ctypes to access gdk_win32_window_get_handle. Took me forever since I had no experience with this - and well it is somehow quite an ugly hack - but well when needed...

Here is the code:

```
        Gdk.threads_enter()            
        #get the gdk window and the corresponding c gpointer
        drawingareawnd = drawingarea.get_property("window")
        #make sure to call ensure_native before e.g. on realize
        if not drawingareawnd.has_native():
            print("Your window is gonna freeze as soon as you move or resize it...")
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
        drawingarea_gpointer = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer(drawingareawnd.__gpointer__, None)            
        #get the win32 handle
        gdkdll = ctypes.CDLL ("libgdk-3-0.dll")
        hnd = gdkdll.gdk_win32_window_get_handle(drawingarea_gpointer)
        #do what you want with it ... I pass it to a gstreamer videosink
        Gdk.threads_leave()
```

Comment: On my PC, calling `gdk_win32_window_get_handle` like this throws an error: `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert`. Doing `gdkdll.gdk_win32_window_get_handle.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]` beforehand appears to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You must first import `GdkX11` for `get_xid()` to be available on the returned `GdkX11Window`.

```
from gi.repository import GdkX11

...

-windowID = self.container.get_window().handle
+windowID = self.container.get_window().get_xid()
```

Comment: I forget mention my environment. I develop for Windows and work on Windows 7 64bits. I already try import GdkX11 but its not work on Windows.

Comment: Well, Windows® uses HWND as it's native window handle (not XID), so you have to adapt to that. I do not have Windows so I can not help. In plain C I would use the `GDK_WINDOW_HWND` macro from `gdk/gdkwin32.h`.

Comment: In GTK+2 works in Windows®. The code _self.container.get_window().handle_ works very well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer advising you to use `.handle` or `.get_xid()` works on GTK2, but not with GTK3 or on MS Windows, which are part of your question.

I've done a lot of digging and found that there is a function in GTK3 which does what you want: `gdk_win32_window_get_handle`, but sadly it is not available in the gi bindings.
You may be able to get to it using ctypes or Cython (which is what I am going to do).